# How to load input file into a table with corresponding date columns?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

If my input file has the below columns with different date formats, then how do I load it in a table with corresponding date columns?

Here's the input file:

```
id,joinDate,projectDate,releaseDate,lastWorkingDate
1,'21-Mar-2015','21/Apr/2015','21/06/2015','21-06-2015'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is a file then by default all the columns will be of string datatype.

So first convert all the columns having date values to informatica date format.
to_date(joinDate,'dd-mon-yyyy')
to_date(projectdate,'dd/mon/yyyy')
to_date(releasedate,'dd/mm/yyyy')
to_date(lastworkingdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') in the expression transformation and map these columns to Target table.